# Private pool (cloud build) can't reach a server hosted on a local site

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

@guillaume-blaquiere and @john-hanley,

Thanks for your feedback, I edited my initial post after your remarks to give you as much info as possible about the context.

In a project A
a network called 'vpc-1' has been created
a sub-network whose ip range is 172.200.10.0/24.
in this project we need a cloud build that will be executed eventually by talend
To make cloud build communicate with the vpc network it is necessary to create an internal IP address range allocated for the private service connection (10.120.0.0/16)

A private connection has been made to pair the vpc network.
One of the commands executed in the workerpool of the cloud build is to connect to the sql server to retrieve data.
For this, a vpn is needed to create a secure tunnel between my gcp project and my local infrastructure.
A standard tunnel based on rules was set up and went well.
I set up a vm in vpc-1, ip 172.200.10.10/24, I can ping and connect to the sql srv on my local infra.
From the sql server of my local network, I can ping this vm too.

According to the google doc https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-services-access?hl=fr#gcloud_9 it is necessary to export the custom routes at the vpc network pairing level.
In the exported routes, we find
-the local subnet route 172.200.10.0/24 and the static route to the sql ip
of my local network 192.168.200.20
I then created a workerpool  in cloud build by indicating the project, the type of machine, etc.
To do a test, I created a .yml file to execute commands with this workerpool.
In the yml file test I run simple ping commands :

```
steps:
  - name: ubuntu
    script: |
      apt update
      apt install telnet iputils-ping traceroute net-tools -y
      ping -c 4 172.200.10.10 (100% success)
      ping -c 4 192.168.200.20 (100% lost)
options:
  pool:
    name: "projects/project-id/locations/europe-north1/workerPools/workpool-test"
```

I wonder if communication is simply possible or not between the workerpool and my on-premise network

Comment: Your question has zero details on what you configured, what you tested, which commands you are running or error messages.

Comment: Can you add details, on the errors, but also on your configuration, of your VPN, routes, firewall, Cloud Build,(...)?

Comment: Hello guys, Thanks for your feedback
I edited my initial post by giving a maximum of information on the infra which was created